# How to change type or React Component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to conditionally wrap some components:

```
class innerComponent extends React.Component{
  //...
}

class oldContainer extends React.Component{
  //...
}

class newContainer extends React.Component{
  //...
}

interface Props = {
  newContainer: boolean;
}

const Component: React.SFC<Props> = props => {
  container = React.Component;
  if (props.newContainer) {
    container = newContainer;
  } else {
    container = oldContainer;
  }
  return (
    <container>
      <innerComponent/>
    </container>
  )
};
```

That is, I need to be able to change the type of a component and use it later on. Is this possible in React? If yes, how to achieve this?

Comment: In JSX, React component types (and therefore class names that extend `React.Component`) must be `TitleCase`, not `camelCase`. Also don't forget to _declare_ your type, not just assign it, e.g. `let Container = props.newContainer ? NewContainer : OldContainer;`

Comment: This could be accomplished more simply with straightforward conditional rendering: ```return (<>{ props.newContainer ? <NewContainer/> : <OldContainer/>}</>)```